# Grouping usage data per week

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create a usage report where I can plot the number of files created per week by each user.  I'm trying to put the data into a DataTable so I can use it in a Chart.  The path I'm headed down is clunky and I'm guessing there is a much more elegant way to do this in Linq.

The File class has an OpenDate and a LastModUser value.  I want to sum up all the files created for a week for each user.  In table form this looks like this:

File#  OpenDate  LastModUser

1       1/1/2015    ASmith

2       1/2/2015    ASmith

3       1/2/2015    DJones

4       1/2/2015    CBanks

The result of this query would return:

Week#  ASmith  DJones  CBanks

1    2  1  1

2  etc etc etc

Here is what I have thus far.

```
    public static DataTable GetFileCountByUserByClient(Int32 clientID, Int32 weeks)
    {
        using (EtaDataModelContainer12 etaDbContext = new EtaDataModelContainer12())
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("week", typeof(Int32));

            // These are all the client's files
            List<File> files = etaDbContext.Files.Where(b => b.ClientClientId == clientID).ToList();

            // Get a list of all users
            List<string> users = files.GroupBy(b => b.LastModUser).Select(b =>b.Key).Distinct().ToList();
            for (int i = 1; i < users.Count(); i++)
            {
                // Create one column per user
                table.Columns.Add(users[i], typeof(string));
            }

            // Add rows to the table based on how many files created in a given week
            DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
            int filecount = 0;

            // Loop through the number of selected weeks (rows in DataTable) and populate sums
            for (int j = 0; j < weeks; j++)
            {
                // Look at each file and determine if it fits in the selected week
                foreach (File item in files)
                {
                    // If a match is found determine what column in the DataTable should be incremented
                }

                table.Rows.Add(j, filecount);

            }


            return table;

        }
    }
```

There has to be a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: It is not very clear what your data looks like.  Can you show the table columns and datatypes?

Comment: You approach is probably the best method.  You are creating a pivot table which linq doesn't handle elegantly.  You need a mod (%) operator to divide by 7 and code to adjust the iterations to the first day of the week.  Getting the first day of the week isn't a simple formula.

Comment: What is `etaDbContext`. Or, what type of LINQ is this?

Answer (score 0):

I think, this can solve your problem. You may need to tune some constant to get it to your grid. The week returned by this query will be number of week from year 0.

```
const long TicksPerWeek = TimeSpan.TicksPerDay * 7;

var userFiles = files.GroupBy(f => f.LastModUser);
var userStats = userFiles.Select(u =>
    u.GroupBy(f => file.Date.Ticks / TicksPerWeek)
        .Select(f => new { week = f.Key, modifiedCount = f.Count()))
```